# Append to buffer using read() in C

Tags: c, file, append, buffer

I want to read data from a text file in blocks of 20 characters into a buffer until the end of the file by using the read() command in C.

```
while (n != 0) {    
    n = read(filedescriptor, buffer, 20);
}
```

This overwrites the buffer each time. Is it possible to append to the buffer using the `read()` command?

Comment: Well, you could actually use the return value to see how many characters have been read, then add that value to `buffer` to have the function append to existing data read before, while at the same time taking extra care not to overflow the buffer, i.e. read more than 20 characters.

Comment: If your buffer is only 20 charachers long, appending data after would squish other data

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely possible.  But you should know for sure how big your buffer is.

So if you have

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 200
char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
int nbuf = 0;       /* number of characters read into buffer */
int r;
```

you could write something like

```
while(nbuf < BUFFER_SIZE) {
    int n_to_read = 20;
    if(nread + n_to_read > BUFFER_SIZE) /* make sure won't overflow buffer */
        n_to_read = BUFFER_SIZE - nread;
    r = read(fd, &buf[nbuf], n_to_read);
    if(r <= 0) break;    /* error / EOF */
    nbuf += r;
}
```

If you want to demonstrate your understanding of the "equivalence" between arrays and pointers in C, you could rewrite that `read` call as

```
    r = read(fd, buf + nbuf, n_to_read);
```

and indeed this is the way many people would write it.

P.S. I would use `fread` and `FILE *` pointers rather than `read` and integer file descriptors.

Comment: Actually, if `r < 0` you should check if `read` was interrupted by a signal by testing if `errno == EINTR` and restart the operation.

Comment: What is happening exactly in `read(fd, &buf[nbuf], BUFFER_SIZE - nbuf);` - why the `&` before `buf`, why the `[nbuf]` after `buf` and why the `BUFFER_SIZE - nbuf`?

Comment: Well, how much do you know about arrays and pointers?  A "buffer", in this context, is an array of characters.  We can have a pointer into an array of characters.  When we call `read`, we give it a pointer telling it where to write the characters it has written for us.  We also tell it how many characters it's allowed to read.  If the pointer is to the beginning of the buffer it can read as many characters as the buffer can hold, but if the pointer is to somewhere in the middle of the buffer we have to tell it to read less.

Comment: But actually my code is wrong, it's no longer reading 20 characters at a time like you asked.  I'll have to fix it.